# How to dynamically resize a Canvas inside a BorderPane with JavaFX

Tags: java, swing, canvas, javafx

I've been using `Swing` for a long time and starting to get into `JavaFX`.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to create a resizable painting area.

What I'd like is the equivalent to the `Swing` code:

```
JPanel parent = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JPanel drawArea = new JPanel(){
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawLine(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.drawLine(getWidth(), 0, 0, getHeight());
    }
};
parent.add(drawArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

This will nicely scale to fit the parent container whenever you change its size.

I'm trying to do the same in `JavaFX` using a `BorderPane` for the parent and a Canvas for the inner control, based on the code here:

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/04/javafx-tip-1-resizable-canvas.html

This works by setting the canvas to the dimensions of the parent component whenever they change - however, this prevents the canvas from shrinking when the the parent ought to shrink since the parent size now includes its child canvas size.  So the only way this example with work is if my canvas uses the stage directly as a parent.  It also seems like a lot of work to set this up.

Is there any way to get a simple `JPanel`-like component that will automatically fit its parent and let me catch a resize event so I can repaint it?

Comment: The example provided in the link, by you, should work flawlessly with a BorderPane. Can you show us what you have already tried?

Comment: Looks like I was putting my Canvas inside of a StackPane (nested within the BorderPane) and trying to use the StackPane to drive the resizing of the canvas component.  When I replaced that with a simple Pane, the resizing worked properly.

Comment: You can still use a StackPane in these situations but you will need to override the layoutChildren() method of the StackPane and then set the Canvas Width and Height manually.  This is not as difficult as it sounds. See the Code below:
@Override
protected void layoutChildren() {
int top = (int) snappedTopInset();
int right = (int) snappedRightInset();
int bot = (int) snappedBottomInset();
int left = (int) snappedLeftInset();
int w = (int) getWidth() - left- right;
int h = (int) getHeight() - top - bot;
canvas.setLayoutX(left);
canvas.setLayoutY(top);
canvas.setWidth(w);
canvas.setHeight(h);